# Flyway Found non-empty schema on empty schema

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, flyway

I am trying to implement DB migration with `Flyway 4.2.0 + Oracle 11g`

I have this empty schema:

[image: schema with no tables]

And when I try to migrate, Flyway says:

> Caused by: `org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException`: Found non-empty
>   schema(s) "`PASHA`" without metadata table! Use `baseline()` or set
>   `baselineOnMigrate` to `true` to initialize the metadata table.

This is the config:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(false);
    flyway.setSchemas("PASHA");
    flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration/oracle");
    flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:test", "login", "password");
    return flyway;
}
```

**Why do I get this message? My base is empty.**

Answer (score 5):

Flyway itself uses a query to check if the schema is empty.

[In the case of oracle, the query is](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/flyway-4.2.0/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/oracle/OracleSchema.java#L76):

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = ?
```

Execute that query (with your owner in the place of `?`) and see if it returns something (it does).

For instance, LOBs that haven't been purged show there. If that's the case, try:

```
purge recyclebin;
```

and the query should be empty now.

Comment: Seems Flyway runs this to see if schema is empty. If schema is empty it seems to ignore the baseline flag even it set to true.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either let Flyway create the schema itself (meaning there should not be a 'PASHA' schema created before hand), or baseline the existing schema (meaning setting your configuration with `flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true)` ).

Basically, Flyway tries to create a schema ('PASHA' in your example) which already exists.

Comment: you may not have noticed but i'm using `flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(false);`

Comment: I meant to say true, sorry. You have to baseline when the schema and/or objects already exist in your target DB. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding all of these helped. But the one without spring actually did the trick! Silly as it is, but just worked!

```
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true
flyway.baseline-on-migrate= true
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
```

Comment: `spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate` and `spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate` as same as the other pair are the same property.

Comment: Yes but something was helped when both included. Didn't do any deeper investigations there. Perhaps my bundle has dependancies for both the versions there.