# Automatically baselining a database with Flyway in a Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to add Flyway to a Spring Boot project. In accordance with [the instructions](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing), I've created my initial DDL script and committed it to `src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__base_version.sql`.

If I run [the baseline command](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/baseline), this will create the `flyway_schema_history` table and set the baseline version therein to 1.

While this works fine for my local database, I would like this to happen automatically on the other developers' local environments, UAT environment, etc.

I tried adding the following property to the Spring Boot config

```
spring:
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
```

I expected this to do the same thing as the baseline command when the Spring Boot app starts up if the `flyway_schema_history` table does not exist, i.e. create this table and insert a row specifying the current schema version, but it didn't.

Is there a way to automatically baseline the database when the app starts up?

Comment: This works for me. If the schema is there and flyway_schema_history alone is missing, it creates the flyway_schema_history and notes the baseline without running any scripts. If the schema is created automatically, then it seems to ignore the baseline flag and just runs the V1.

Comment: More preciesly.. flyway checks if schema is empty and ignores the baseline flag if schema is empty: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61626769/1364747

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a `migrate` command to actually trigger that.
More info can be referred here:
https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/configuration/parameters/flyway/baseline-on-migrate.